# How does ApplicationRecord association method lookup work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

As I understand Ruby inheritance and method lookup, when a child instance calls a parent's instance method, which in turn calls a method that's named in both parent and child, the scope is still at the child instance. So this will happen:

```
class Foo 

  def method1
    "foo"
  end

  def method2
    puts method1
  end
end

class Bar < Foo

  def method1
    "bar"
  end
end

Bar.new.method2
=> "bar"
```

However, when I do what I think is a similar thing with ActiveRecord associations, I don't get what I'd expect:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :orders
  has_many :order_items, through: :orders
end

class Bar < Foo

  has_many :orders, -> { where(attribute1: 1) }
end
```

When I call `bar.orders` I get what I expect. But when I call `bar.order_items` I get the same result as if I had called `foo.order_items` (the query scope is not used). If I include `has_many :orders_items, through: :orders` in **bar.rb** it behaves as I expect. Why do ApplicationRecords behave this way? Am I comparing apples to oranges?

Comment: Am I comparing apples to oranges? - yes - the first example is inheritance of instance methods while  `has_many :orders` is meta-programming that operates on the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Max states in the comment, you're not defining methods, you're calling them, when you'r using the meta programming, so there is no inheritance involved.